# Ideas for custom `do`/`let` syntax (without macros)?

Tags: clojure, macros, monads, state-monad

I just built a state monad "object", and would like to be able to bind steps to variables, and link up successive computations, as if with `bind`/`>>=`, like how haskell works with monads, and like how clojure's various monad libs work. Here's my monad:

```
(def state-m
  (let [pure (fn [x] (fn [s] [x s]))
        bind (fn [mv mf] (fn [s] ; mv :: s -> (a, s) || mf :: a -> (s -> (b, s))
                           (let [[a s'] (mv s)]
                             ((mf a) s'))))

        then     (fn [mv mf] (bind mv (fn [_] mf))) ; eg `>>`
        get-s    (fn [s] [s s])
        put-s    (fn [s] (fn [_] [nil s]))
        update-s (fn [f] (fn [s] [nil (f s)]))] ; f :: s->s

    {:pure     pure
     :bind     bind
     :then     then
     :get-s    get-s
     :put-s    put-s
     :update-s update-s}))
```

Here's an example of using it:

```
(let [pure     (:pure state-m)
      >>=      (:bind state-m)
      >>       (:then state-m)
      get-s    (:get-s state-m)
      put-s    (:put-s state-m)
      update-s (:update-s state-m)]
  (and (= [:v :s] ((pure :v) :s))
       (= [5 :state] ((>>= (pure 3)
                           (fn [x] (pure (+ 2 x))))
                      :state))
       (= [3 3] ((>>= get-s (fn [n] (pure n))) 3))
       (= [4 5] ((>>= get-s (fn [n] (>> (put-s (+ n 1))
                                        (pure n)))) 4))
       (= [4 8] ((>>= get-s (fn [n] (>> (update-s (partial * 2))
                                        (pure n)))) 4))))
```

It's a little verbose. I don't mind right now, but I *would* like to be able to use `do` syntax, eg:

```
(my-do [a (get-s)
        _ (put-s 33)
        b (* 2 a)
        _ (put-s 44)
        c (* a b)]
  c)
```

Or even some thready kind of function (although I know clj's threads are macros), eg:

```
(my-> (pure 1)
      (>>= (fn [a] ...))
      (>>= (fn [b] ...))
      (>> (* a b))) ; notice non-local bindings `a` and `b` are available here
```

I can look at existing monad libs in clojure for how to accomplish this with macros, and that's fine. I'm curious how this could be achieved without the use of macros, even if just an exercise to experiment with how it could be done.

I am aware of `binding`s in clojure, but haven't used them. How could I use this, or other appropriate constructs to achieve `do`ish syntax?

Comment: Why exclude macros?

Comment: @Carcigenicate good question, just to see if I can, and how it would look. It doesn't have to look exactly like `do` syntax, just something more convenient than a million nested binds, without using a new macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those two styles are possible without a macro. Macros are *the* construct for introducing new syntactic structures in any lisp, so if you want a new syntax macros are the way to go.

Comment: sure, but I'm thinking there has to be *some* way to simplify things without needing macros. Like, say I had a language where macros were awkward or not even possible and I wanted to simplify syntax. How could I? Even looping over a list of expressions could be possible, I just need to figure out how...

Comment: Macros are exactly the feature added to the language to do the specific thing you want to do. You are asking, "How can I make my car accelerate without using the gas pedal?" Maybe some solutions exist, such as putting your car in neutral and rolling it down a steep hill, but are those really the solutions you want?

Comment: I agree, and understand the importance of macros, and how they match my use case besides me not wanting to use macros. I don't necessarily need a new syntactic structure, just something to reduce the boiler plate, and for learning's sake, doesn't use macros. Ex: I just found this in JS: https://curiosity-driven.org/monads-in-javascript#do and I'm digesting it now

Answer (score 0):

Macros only extra purpose is to delay evaluation when compared to functions as a method of abstraction. If you were to use functions for everything you need to change the contract so that the user passes functions as arguments where the macro would have delayed the evaluation of expressions. Here is an example of remakeing `if`:

```
(defn if* [p a c] 
  (if p (a) (c)))

(if* true
     (fn [] 1)
     (fn [] 2)) ; ==> 1
```

You never need macros if you can cope with more boilerplate, but in the long run I'm grateful all my arguments doesn't have to be thunks.

The rule of thumb is to try doing abstractions with functions, but where that is not possible without too much fuzz using macros to transform easier syntax to boilerplate is the most important feature of the languages that has them. You are not that dependent on new versions of the language in Clojure as with Java since most features are possible with more boilerplate and macros simplify the syntax such that it would be indistinguishable with a new language feature.